# Can I use "an" before plural noun?

Tags: grammatical-number, articles

I wrote in my manuscript that;
"Additional 17 human samples not preserved in formaldehyde were provided for age dating."

But my English proofreader corrected that
"An additional 17 human samples not preserved in formaldehyde were provided for age dating."

She explained the reason as "I added an 'An' here because you are starting a sentence with this information (and the article here can help in emphasizing the action that is going on in this sentence). "

I need further explanation.

Comment: Lacking context, it's difficult to tell what your question is. The proofreader has that context. For example, in some contexts, "Additionally, 17 human samples not preserved etc." would work as well as "An additional etc.", but in other contexts, it might not. What clearly does not work is the sentence as you wrote it.

Comment: I agree that starting "Additional 17 human samples..." is wrong. Perhaps "An additional 17 human samples ..." could be seen as short for "An additional *quantity of* 17 human samples ..."?